# Regex: match all but two dots

Tags: regex, validation, path

I'm trying to validate a system path. This path is valid if it begins with some dirs and don't contain two dots one another.

```
#valid path
/home/user/somedir/somedir_2
#evil path
/home/user/../somedir_2/
```

I know how to check for two dots in a path:

```
\.\. or [\.]{2}
```

But I really want to do something like that:

```
/home/user/<match everything but two dots>/somedir_2/
```

so that "match everything but two dots" can be everything but two dots.

I have tried:

```
/home/user/[^\.{2}]*/somedir_2/
```

but without any success.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Can you provide a sample and what you would want to extract from it?  Would you want to take `he..llo` and extract `hello`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification isn't clear, but you can use negative lookahead to do something like this:

```
^(?!.*thatPattern)thisPattern$
```

The above would match strings that matches `thisPattern`, but not if it contains a match of `thatPattern`.

Here's an example ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/pGXPocFcx2)):

```
^(?!.*aa)[a-z]*$
```

This would match `^[a-z]*$`, but not if it contains `aa` anywhere.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
^/home/user/(?!.*\.\.).*$
```

will match your good pattern and reject your evil one.